# heroku docpad paged cleanurls 404 error

Tags: heroku, clean-urls, docpad

Tell me, why has stopped working paged or cleanurls plugin.

Rather, paging works, but gives 404 page.

The only problem on heroku.

Example: altyncev.ru/posts

[Config](https://github.com/npofopr/_altyncev/blob/master/docpad.coffee) And [posts file](https://github.com/npofopr/_altyncev/blob/master/src/documents/posts.html.eco) in my repo.

Global changes are not made.

Heroku logs ^ gist.github.com/npofopr/5775870

Comment: Have you checked this? http://docpad.org/docs/deploy#for-deployment-to-heroku

Comment: yes, I'm checked this

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

1. Inside your `package.json` file, change `"node": "0.8",` to `"node": "0.10",` that way it will  use node 0.10 instead of 0.8 for your site
2. Inside your `package.json` file, change all of the docpad plugin version values to `"2.x"` instead of things like `"~2.0.3"` that way it will always use the latest release compatible with your docpad version (rather than just the latest revision release) - see [semver](http://semver.org/) for more information
3. Run `heroku logs` to get the runtime logs, as the logs returned when you deploy are just the deployment logs - which appear that everything is working great, so running `heroku logs` will be able to tell you if something has gone wrong post-deployment. Once done, can you upload the `heroku logs` result somewhere, and update your question to include a link to it, and I'll take a look.

Comment: I'm upgrade node to 0.10, but dont work.
[heroku logs](https://gist.github.com/npofopr/5803344)
Maybe this is not the log?)

Comment: And with node 0.10 paged plugin don't work.
And http://altyncev.ru/posts.1 shows 404 error.
http://altyncev.ru/posts.1.html worked.
Maybe the problem heroku?